# Aspx VB show binary image in GridView

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I had uploaded my image into binary form in Microsoft Sql Server but it cannot display in the GridView although it can show in a test query.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
        <Columns>
            <asp:ImageField DataAlternateTextField="Image" DataImageUrlField="Image" DataImageUrlFormatString="~/Image/{0}"
                HeaderText="Image">
            </asp:ImageField>
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Test Query:

[image]

Grid View:
[image]

Comment: For a start it seems obvious, without even looking at the documentation, that `DataImageUrlField="Image" DataImageUrlFormatString="~/Image/{0}"` are properties for specifying a URL to an image, not a binary image field from the database. That's clear just from their names. Therefore the GridView is trying to display an image from a filename, but the file does not exist. Anyway, this question has been answered before - see the suggested duplicate for a solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.Byte\[\] shows in gridview instead of an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211292/system-byte-shows-in-gridview-instead-of-an-image)

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply and i had changed my code become 
<img src="data:Image/jpeg;base64,<%# Eval("Image") %>" /> 
but still cannot show yet

Comment: Ok but that's not what the answer to that question says you have to do. There's more you have to put in the image tag. Look at it again more carefully. The details are important.